# Generate Demand Line in R, that grows with inflation

Tags: r

I need to create the blue tick line on R. Basically I have information on the values in red and in yellow for different companies. I need to write a code that does: whatever the sum of yellow and red was in 2022 for company x, the blue line of company x should start at that value, and then increase 2% to 3% every year (which is why it is so tick).Can anyone help please? An example would be a company that in 2022 has 20 for red, and 10 for yellow. In this case, the blue line should start at 30 in 2022, 30* 1,02 or 1,03 in 2023, etc. Sorry for adding no database but I am not sure if I can legally share it. So anyone would be so kind to help, would be great.

[image]

Example:

A   2022  100   Red
A   2022   20   Yellow
A   2022   120 (100 +20)   Blue
A   2023  100   Red
A   2023   50   Yellow
A   2023   120 * 1,02   Blue
A   2024  130   Red
A   2024   55   Yellow
A   2024   120 * 1,02 * 1,02   Blue

By every year that goes by, the original sum of yellow and red in 2022 increases by 2%

Comment: Could you maybe use artifical Data like you provided with the text in code form. Maybe just a Dataframe with the inputs and the target output. I personally dont understand what you mean with "2% or 3%". How do we know which percentage to take? is this another Input?

Comment: the blue line does not start at the sum of red and yellow in the example. It starts at approximately the level of red.

Comment: @langtang it starts at 2021 but there is no yellow data in this example

Comment: @Sandwichnick ive added an example for one company, did it help? thank you

Comment: okay, so the yellow here is added to the red.. in your text example yellow is consistently less than red, but in the image yellow is higher than red, so I guess you mean the yellow in the plot is added to (stacked on) the red

Comment: @langtang its basically summing red + yellow in 2022 and then taking that 2022 value and grow it by 2% a year throughout the years

Comment: ok, sorry to be confused. Getting the value of the blue is straightforward - see below. If you need help with the plotting, let us know.

Comment: @langtang what you did is great, and helps a lot thank you. One thing: I have more than one company, i.e., no only A but also B and C... etc. So i need a blue line for each company. Dont worry too much about the plot, I just need to have a initial value of 2022 and respective growth for each company

Comment: sure, added in answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `d` is your data (say, with multiple companies), then getting the blue data for each company is straightforward

```
inner_join(
  d, d %>% 
    filter(y==2022) %>% 
    mutate(blue=red+yellow) %>% 
    select(company, blue),
  by="company"
) %>% 
  mutate(blue = blue*(1.02^(y-2022)))

# A tibble: 6 x 5
  company     y   red yellow  blue
  <chr>   <int> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 A        2022   100     20  120 
2 A        2023   100     50  122.
3 A        2024   130     55  125.
4 B        2022   200     15  215 
5 B        2023   205     18  219.
6 B        2024   210     30  224.
```

Input Data:

```
d = tibble(
  company=c(rep("A",3),rep("B",3)),
  y = rep(2022:2024,2),
  red= c(100, 100, 130, 200, 205, 210),
  yellow = c(20, 50,55, 15,18, 30)
)
```

Here is an extended example for plotting, using fake data that tries to approximate the plot in the original post. If `d` is your data for red and yellow (see below for structure/generation of `d`), then you can:

1. Create the blue data

```
base = colSums(d[d$year==2022,2])
blue_data = tibble(year=2022:2040) %>%
  mutate(value=base*(1.02^(year-2022)), 
         group="blue", 
         plotmax = base*(1.03^(year-2022)),
         plotmin = value)
```

2. Manipulate `d` and `blue_data` to create plot data

```
# create plot data
plot_data <- rbind(
  d %>% mutate(
    plotmax = c(
      d %>% filter(group=="red") %>% pull(value),
      d %>% filter(year>=2021) %>% group_by(year) %>% summarize(value=sum(value)) %>% pull(value)),
    plotmin = c(
      rep(0,times=nrow(d %>% filter(group=="red"))),
      d %>% filter(year>=2021, group=="red") %>% pull(value)
      ),
  blue_data
)
```

3. Plot the data in `plot_data`

```
manual_values = c("red"="red", "blue"="blue", "yellow"="yellow")
ggplot(plot_data, aes(x=year, color=group,fill=group)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=plotmin, ymax=plotmax)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values=manual_values)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=manual_values) + 
  theme(legend.position='bottom')
```

[image: mfta]

Input data (`d`)

```
structure(list(year = c(2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L, 2020L, 
2021L, 2022L, 2023L, 2024L, 2025L, 2026L, 2027L, 2028L, 2029L, 
2030L, 2031L, 2032L, 2033L, 2034L, 2035L, 2036L, 2037L, 2038L, 
2039L, 2040L, 2021L, 2022L, 2023L, 2024L, 2025L, 2026L, 2027L, 
2028L, 2029L, 2030L, 2031L, 2032L, 2033L, 2034L, 2035L, 2036L, 
2037L, 2038L, 2039L, 2040L), value = c(220, 242.857142857143, 
265.714285714286, 288.571428571429, 311.428571428571, 334.285714285714, 
357.142857142857, 380, 360, 352.941176470588, 345.882352941176, 
338.823529411765, 331.764705882353, 324.705882352941, 317.647058823529, 
310.588235294118, 303.529411764706, 296.470588235294, 289.411764705882, 
282.352941176471, 275.294117647059, 268.235294117647, 261.176470588235, 
254.117647058824, 247.058823529412, 240, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 
30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50), group = c("red", 
"red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", 
"red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", 
"red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "yellow", "yellow", 
"yellow", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", 
"yellow", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", 
"yellow", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow")), row.names = c(NA, -46L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```